# i am trying to customize Django default admin dashboard by installing jazz-min lib raise but getting error

Tags: python, django, customization, admin

**The error i get when i install the jazmmin and when i check the admin dashboard**

```
AttributeError at /admin/
'User' object has no attribute 'get_all_permissions'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 4.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'User' object has no attribute 'get_all_permissions'
Exception Location: C:\Users\dawat\OneDrive\Desktop\project\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py, line 268, in inner
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.sites.index
Python Executable:  C:\Users\dawat\OneDrive\Desktop\project\myenv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\dawat\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\project',
 'C:\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\dawat\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\project\\myenv',
 'C:\\Users\\dawat\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\project\\myenv\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 16 May 2023 05:46:26 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\dawat\OneDrive\Desktop\project\myenv\Lib\site-packages\jazzmin\templates\admin\base.html, error at line 73

*

User' object has no attribute 'get_all_permissions

*
63                          <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
64                      </li>
65                  {% else %}
66                      <li class="nav-item">
67                          <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}" class="brand-link">
68                              <img src="{% static jazzmin_settings.site_logo %}" alt="{{ jazzmin_settings.site_header }} Logo" class="{{ jazzmin_settings.site_logo_classes }} brand-image" style="opacity: .8; margin: 0 0 0 5px;">
69                          </a>
70                      </li>
71                  {% endif %}
72  
73                  {% get_top_menu user request.current_app|default:"admin" as top_menu %}
74                  {% for link in top_menu %}
75                      <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block{% if link.children %} dropdown{% endif %}">
76                          {% if link.children %}
77                              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
78                                  {{ link.name }}
79                              </a>
80                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
81                                  {% for child in link.children %}
82                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ child.url }}" {% if link.new_window %}target="_blank"{% endif %}>{{ child.name }}</a>
83                                  {% endfor %}
```

**i inclued the jazzmin in my install app**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jazzmin',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'customer'
]


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'
```

i have user Auth_user_model to specify a custom user model to replace the default user model. By default, Django provides a User model that includes some basic fields such as username, email, password

here is the model of user

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db.models.fields.related import OneToOneField
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, phone_number, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')

        if not username:
            raise ValueError('User must have a username')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            phone_number=phone_number,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, phone_number, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
            phone_number=phone_number,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superadmin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    UNKNOWN = 1
    CUSTOMER = 2

    ROLE_CHOICE = (
        (UNKNOWN, 'Unknown'),
        (CUSTOMER, 'Customer'),
    )

    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)

    # required fields
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'phone_number']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    
    def get_role(self):
        if self.role == 1:
            user_role = 'Unknown'
        elif self.role == 2:
            user_role = 'Customer'
        return user_role


----------
```